# can not create jsfiddle properly to overlap divs on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have not been able to create jsfiddle for my actual question.

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
  item1
</div>
<div class="item2">
    item2
</div>
```

CSS

```
item1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    top:5%;
}

.item2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    top:8%;
    left:1%;
    display:none;
}
```

I am trying to display item2 on item1 hover

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/23/

But on hover it does not display item2. It should right??

please help?

Comment: The title should tell what the problem is, not about your jsfiddle experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$` at the start of your jQuery selectors.

Change this:

```
(".item1").hover(
    function() {
      (".item2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

To this:

```
$(".item1").hover(
    function() {
      $(".item2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/25/*

Answer (score 1):

you have missed `$` (jQuery function) around your () should be:

```
$(".item1").hover(
    function() {
      $(".item2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

not

```
(".item1").hover(
    function() {
      (".item2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you also would need to hide it as the item1 looses the hover

```
$(".item1").hover(
    function() {
      $(".item2").show();
    },function(){
    $(".item2").hide()
    }
);
```

And offcourse I changed your code of making **change to css property of display** to **show and hide.** achieving the same effect

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$(".item1").on('hover', function() {
      $(".item2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery was incorrect. jQuery requires a `$` before selectors, and `.mouseover` instead of `.hover` if you don't need anything for `mouseleave`. I also cleaned up your code by condensing lines and changing `.css` to `.show()`.

```
$(".item1").mouseover(function() {
    $(".item2").show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/30/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this you miss $ symbol

```
$(".item1").hover(
function() {
  $(".item2").css("display", "block");
}
);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/31/)